# How to merge multiple dicts with the same specific key value?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have list of dicts/key-value pairs like this:

```py
list = [{'mid': 123, 'msg': 'sometext', 'antivirus': 'positive'},
        {'mid': 123, 'msg': 'sometext2', 'antivirus': 'positive'},
        {'mid': 456, 'msg': 'sometext3', 'antivirus': 'positive'},
        {'mid': 456, 'msg': 'sometext4', 'antivirus': 'positive'},
        {'mid': 789, 'msg': 'sometext5', 'antivirus': 'positive'}]
```

I want the result to be a new list of dict (in most efficient way, if possible) grouping them by the value of '**mid**' key:

```py
result = [{'mid': 123, 'msg': 'sometext,sometext2', 'antivirus': 'positive,positive'}, 
          {'mid': 456, 'msg': 'sometext3,sometext4', 'antivirus': 'positive,positive'},
          {'mid': 789, 'msg': 'sometext5', 'antivirus': 'positive'}]
```

Comment: Wouldn't you rather just group the events by key (`mid`) instead of merging them (thus making them alot harder to work with...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not super thrilled about this approach, but it'd get you there.  It iterates over the list of dicts `lst` using a `defaultdict` to group by the `mid` value, then iterates over *that* to produce your output, joining the values of the `msg` and `antivirus` keys.

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [{'mid': 123, 'msg': 'sometext', 'antivirus': 'positive'},
       {'mid': 123, 'msg': 'sometext2', 'antivirus': 'positive'},
       {'mid': 456, 'msg': 'sometext3', 'antivirus': 'positive'},
       {'mid': 456, 'msg': 'sometext4', 'antivirus': 'positive'},
       {'mid': 789, 'msg': 'sometext5', 'antivirus': 'positive'}]

dd = defaultdict(list)
for d in lst:
    key = d['mid']
    dd[key].append(d)

output = []
for (k,v) in dd.items():
    output.append({
        'mid':       k,
        'msg':       ','.join(x['msg']       for x in v),
        'antivirus': ','.join(x['antivirus'] for x in v),
    })

print(output)
```

```
[
  {'mid': 123, 'msg': 'sometext,sometext2', 'antivirus': 'positive,positive'}, 
  {'mid': 456, 'msg': 'sometext3,sometext4', 'antivirus': 'positive,positive'}, 
  {'mid': 789, 'msg': 'sometext5', 'antivirus': 'positive'}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use pandas dataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

lst  = [{'mid': 123, 'msg': 'sometext', 'antivirus': 'positive'},
        {'mid': 123, 'msg': 'sometext2', 'antivirus': 'positive'},
        {'mid': 456, 'msg': 'sometext3', 'antivirus': 'positive'},
        {'mid': 456, 'msg': 'sometext4', 'antivirus': 'positive'},
        {'mid': 789, 'msg': 'sometext5', 'antivirus': 'positive'}]

d = (pd.DataFrame(lst)
       .groupby(['mid'])
       .agg(','.join)
       .reset_index()
       .to_dict('r'))

print (d)
```

output:

```
[{'mid': 123, 'antivirus': 'positive,positive', 'msg': 'sometext,sometext2'}, 
 {'mid': 456, 'antivirus': 'positive,positive', 'msg': 'sometext3,sometext4'}, 
 {'mid': 789, 'antivirus': 'positive', 'msg': 'sometext5'}]
```

Comment: Unless the OP is using pandas already, I'm not sure requiring and importing the 2-ton pandas package to solve this is a great idea

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to call one of your variables (`list`) the same as a builtin, so I use `l` here

using an intermediate defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict


intermediate = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for record in l:
    mid = record["mid"]
    for key, value in record.items():
        if key == "mid":
            continue
        intermediate[mid][key].append(value)

result = [
    {"mid": mid, **{key: ",".join(value) for key, value in attributes.items()}}
    for mid, attributes in intermediate.items()
]
result
```

Answer (score 0):

(list is a keyword in python, so I changed the name to mylist)
Here's your obligatory one-liner:

```
import itertools; map(lambda sub: reduce(lambda a,b: { key : ",".join(set(filter(lambda x: x!='', [str(a.get(key, ''))] + [str(b.get(key, ''))]))) for key in set(a.keys() + b.keys()) }, sub, {}), map(lambda sub: list(sub[1]), itertools.groupby(mylist, lambda lst: lst['mid'])))
```

less obnoxiously:

```
import itertools
groups = map(lambda sub: list(sub[1]), itertools.groupby(mylist, lambda lst: lst['mid'])) # get the dicts organized into groups on key 'mid'

def joindicts(a,b):
    result = dict()
    for key in set(a.keys() + b.keys()): # get union of keys for both dicts
        val_a = str(a.get(key, ''))
        val_b = str(b.get(key, ''))
        val = ','.join([x for x in [val_a] + [val_b] if x != ''])
        result.update({key:val})
    return result

map(lambda sub: reduce(joindicts, sub, {}), groups)
```